# Failed to create a workflow job, 401 Unauthorized

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've been testing dataflow jobs, submit job from local server and create dataflow jobs in the cloud, it's been successful, now I'm trying to set it up in prod which is on one of GCEs in the cloud, I got this error:

"Failed to create a workflow job: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized"

Does this mean that submitting/initiating job can only be done outside the cloud so that the cluster of GCEs can be span up properly?

And I also authenticated using "gcloud auth login" still no luck.....

Answer (score 2):

This error most likely means the request to submit your Dataflow job didn't have a proper credential. When you submit a Dataflow job from a GCE instance Dataflow will try to use the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication) attached to that VM to authorize the request.

When you created the GCE VM did you:

1. Attach a service account to the VM (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using) for instructions)?
2. Include the required scopes? You will need at least the scope
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Comment: Hi Jeremy Lewi, I try to submit dataflow job from an existing GCE VM, I didn't create it nor attache any service account to that VM, what can I do in this case?

Comment: or if I cant add a service account to an existing VM, is there any way I can make dataflow use personal account to authenticate?